# WPF - binding complex objects to simple controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have created a class named "BoundProperty" which contains a property "Value".

Binding to a property which is an instance of that class looks this way
(Age is a BoundProperty):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Age.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Is there a way to make the binding look this way and additionally still retain it two-way?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Age, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I can't use implicit/explicit conversion operators, for this "BoundProperty" initialization requires special parameters, which need to be copied from original object.

Thanks,
AD

Comment: where / how do you use that BoundProperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Value is public you can use ValueConverter:

```
public class BoundPropertyConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var age = value as BoundProperty;
        if (age == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return age.Value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int age;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out age))
            return new BoundProperty() {Value = age};
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in xaml define namespace to this converter

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace"
```

And then in Resources area write something like this:

```
<converters:BoundPropertyConverter x:Key="BoundPropertyConverter"/>
```

And last but not least:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Age, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoundPropertyConverter}" />
```

Comment: That's great but I would like to use this converter implicitly and not mention it in my xaml code. Is there a way to do this, for example by implementing some interface?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any other way to do this. This what I've posted is the best solution of that kind of problem. I think so...